# Setting a default placeholder date using Angular and ng-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to set a placeholder date (now) for a datepicker, however can't work out how to do it.

Please help.

```ts
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { NgbDateCustomParserFormatter} from 'dateformat';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-datepicker-popup',
  templateUrl: './datepicker-popup.html',

   valuedate = new Date();

})


export class NgbdDatepickerPopup {
  model = {year: 2017, month: 8, day: 8};
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" ngbDatepicker placeholder="{{model}}" class="form-control" #d="ngbDatepicker" [(ngModel)]="model" />
  <button (click)="d.toggle()">Toggle</button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So a couple of things here:

A) "AngularJS" generally refers to Angular 1.x, and this is clearly Angular 2+ you're working with here

B) Judging by the fact that you are trying to place valuedate inside of your Component decorator instead of as a property inside your class definition, I'd say you need to learn a lot about Angular before wanting to tackle building your own component to do this.  There are several component libraries that will give you a datepicker including [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) and [Kendo](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/).

C) The double curly brace syntax is for interpolation, which essentially inserts text.  If you really are needing to roll your own component here, something like this might work (note: uses the momentjs library):

```html
<input type="text" ngbDatepicker placeholder="placeholder" class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="valuedate" />
```

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { NgbDateCustomParserFormatter} from 'dateformat';
import * as moment from 'moment-mini';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-datepicker-popup',
  templateUrl: './datepicker-popup.html',

})
export class NgbdDatepickerPopup {
  valuedate = new Date();
  placeholder: string = moment().format('MM/DD/YYYY');
}
```

D) There are some other issues with your code.  You need to implement the ControlValueAccessor interface for ngModel to work in a custom component like that.

Comment: OP edited his question after I saw it to update AngularJS to Angular, disregard A.

Answer (score 0):

Create a format for your placeholder:

```
present : Date  = new Date();
model           = 
{
    year : this.present.getFullYear(), 
    month: this.present.getMonth()+1, 
    day  : this.present.getDate()
};

placeHolderText = this.model.year + '-' + this.model.month + '-' + this.model.day;
```

Then

```
<input type="text" ngbDatepicker placeholder="placeHolderText" ...
```